# Docker doesn't RUN command as USER

Tags: unix, docker, virtualization

I am new with `Docker` and I am having trouble writing my `Dockerfile`. The thing is that I created a user named `jonas523` which I want to execute a shell command. So I put it in this `Dockerfile` and when I go inside my fresh container, I observe that the command was not used with the new user I created.

I think I didn't understand the `USER` instruction provided by `Docker`:

```
USER jonas523

RUN \
    echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin" >> /home/jonas523/.bash_profile \
    && echo "ANT_HOME=/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin" >> /home/jonas523/.bash_profile \
    && echo "export JAVA_HOME" >> /home/jonas523/.bash_profile \
    && echo "export ANT_HOME" >> /home/jonas523/.bash_profile \
    && echo "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$ANT_HOME" >> /home/jonas523/.bash_profile \
    && echo "export PATH" >> /home/jonas523/.bash_profile

RUN source ~/.bash_profile
```

Could anyone tell me about using of the `USER` instruction. What is the difference between the `RUN` and `CMD` instructions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#user):

> The USER instruction sets the user name or UID to use when running the image and for any following RUN directives.

It doesn't create the user, though. You need to have done that already (e.g. with an earlier `RUN` instruction.)

> What is the difference between the "RUN" and "CMD" instructions ?

`RUN` is for progressively "layering up" a docker image to, say, install necessary dependencies (e.g. `RUN apt-get install ....`). You can have a number of `RUN` instructions in a Dockerfile, and they all get executed when you build your image (ignoring the build cache for simplicity).

`CMD` instructions do NOT get executed during `docker build ...`, but rather specifies a command you want the container to execute at `docker run ...` You can only have 1 `CMD` instruction in a Dockerfile.

Comment: Ok it's clearer now. But how do I know which user is used when I use the instruction "CMD" ?
So if e.g I say :

"USER jonas523"
"RUN whatever"

I am sure that whatever will be build with the user jonas523 ? Is that correct ?