# Executing command as specific user in docker container

Tags: docker

After creating a container in docker

```
docker run -it -d --name my-container my-image
```

I want to execute a command as specific user (according to [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/))

```
docker exec -it --user my-user my-container echo $USER
```

But this outputs `root`

How can I execute a command as specific user in docker container?

Answer (score 3):

Quite apart from the whether the user exists in the docker container, I think you should also understand when `$USER` is resolved. When you run this command in your shell:

```
docker exec -it --user my-user my-container echo $USER
```

The string `$USER` is replaced with `root` before even calling upon the `docker` executable. (I'm assuming you're running it as as `root`, otherwise I've no idea where it's from.)

To avoid this, you'd have to escape the `$`, like this:

```
docker exec -it --user my-user my-container echo \$USER
```

When I tested this, the value of `$USER` was not known to the shell inside the container. If you want to see that the user running inside the container is indeed your user, try this:

```
docker exec -it --rm --user my-user my-container /bin/id -u
```

That will print the userid of `my-user`. Unfortunately, that user won't exist until you create it in the container, so it doesn't have a name. Another person has already posted a link in this question to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26505538/9079713).  You need to create the user in the docker image if you want to use it during the runtime

Comment: My image has the user already, I can start a bash shell with `my-user` through `docker exec -it --user my-user my-container bin/bash`. This enters bash as user `my-user`.